# solana$ ./cargo build => "error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1"

Tags: error, cargo

I try to install the Solana chain locally but when I execute the `./cargo build` command, i fall on this fail: `` error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1 ``

But if I do a `./cargo build --release` i have no error and the compilation is successful. I guess i should strictly follow the process and use `./cargo build`, right?
I searched extensively on the web how to fix this `cc` fail but not solution found. Do you have an idea how to fix this?
Thank you for your help ;-)

Repo: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana

Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (WSL)
rustc 1.75.0
rustup 1.26.0
rustfmt 1.7.0-stable
cargo 1.75.0
rustup toolchain: stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)\

Below is where the error starts + after the 3 errors resumed (I cut big bunches of data):

```
...
   Compiling solana-cargo-registry v1.18.0 (/home/davis/github/blockchains/solana-labs/solana/cargo-registry)
   Compiling solana-stake-accounts v1.18.0 (/home/davis/github/blockchains/solana-labs/solana/stake-accounts)
 = note: LC_ALL="C" PATH="/home/davis/.rustup/toolchains/1.75.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin:/home/davis/.cargo/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/wsl/lib:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Common
 (...)
 
 x-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "-o" "/home/davis/github/blockchains/solana-labs/solana/target/debug/deps/solana_install_init-a2a280b3413cfbab" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-pie" "-Wl,-z,relro,-z,now" "-nodefaultlibs"
  = note: collect2: fatal error: ld terminated with signal 9 [Killed]
          compilation terminated.


error: could not compile `solana-install` (bin "solana-install-init") due to previous error
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
  |
  = note: LC_ALL="C" PATH="/home/davis/.rustup/toolchains/1.75.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin:/home/davis/.cargo/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/wsl/lib:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Intel/Shared Libraries/redist/intel64/compiler:/mnt/c/Windows/system32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt
  (...)
  
    = note: collect2: fatal error: ld terminated with signal 9 [Killed]
          compilation terminated.


error: could not compile `solana-install` (bin "solana-install") due to previous error
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
  |
  = note: LC_ALL="C" PATH="/home/davis/.rustup/toolchains/1.75.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin:/home/davis/.cargo/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/wsl/lib:/mnt/c/Pro
  (...)
  
    = note: collect2: fatal error: ld terminated with signal 9 [Killed]
          compilation terminated.


error: could not compile `solana-tokens` (bin "solana-tokens") due to previous error
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
  |
  = note: LC_ALL="C" PATH="/home/davis/.rustup/toolchains/1.75.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin:/home/davis/.cargo/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/u
  (...)
  
  solana-c936d09e9fab7ff5" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-pie" "-Wl,-z,relro,-z,now" "-nodefaultlibs"
  = note: collect2: fatal error: ld terminated with signal 9 [Killed]
          compilation terminated.


error: could not compile `solana-cli` (bin "solana") due to previous error
```

Comment: Can you post the entire error? This output is missing the actual error.

Comment: SEJeff, thank you for your reply. 
I updated the code window by adding the error messages. Is it enough for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically this happens if your machine is running out of RAM, triggering the OOM killer to start deleting processes.

Some parts of the build can be extremely greedy for RAM, so your best bet is to limit the number of concurrent jobs, which will limit the amount of RAM used by the build.

Try specifying the number of jobs to something lower than the number of CPUs on the machine, ie:

```
./cargo build -j 2
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! That was the trick indeed. Your solution works. I first tried with ./cargo build -j 2 and i noticed that the building went more through, almost at the end but it failed. So i tried ./cargo build -j 1 and then the job could finish. Fantastic !!
I was on a laptop that is maybe not enough powerfull for that. I thought this laptop way stronger. It is  a 8 cores: 
AMD Ryzen 7 5800HS with Radeon Graphics 3.20 Gh ; 16 Gb RAM ; 64-bit x64

Comment: Geez, 16GB RAM is pretty good, I'm surprised that wasn't able to make it through with more than 1 concurrent job. Either way, I'm glad that it worked out!